# Neovim keymap <C-l> fails, stuck to clear screen

Tags: neovim

I'm attempting to map `<C-l>` in normal mode but it keeps clearing the screen.
Configuration is in Lua and the line is `keymap("n", "<C-l>", "<C-w>l", opts)`
Other keymaps like `<C-k>` are working with `keymap("n", "<C-k>", "<C-w>k", opts)`

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on WSL in Windows
My shell is bash, version 5.1.16

I've attempted to remove the binding in bash with `bind -r "\C-l"` but is only works in bash and not in neovim (or htop for the matter)